# Problems with having 2 dim dates in ssas/power bi?

Tags: date, powerbi, ssas

I have a basic model with a fact table, and 2 dimensions (one of them is Date dimension).

Now, a new column with a date has been added to the fact table… Therefore I have created a second ‘Dim Date’ and connected to it:
[image]

I have the next doubts:

Can I have any problem in my .pbix or cube if I use 2 dim dates?

Shall I mark this new ‘dim date’ also as ‘Mark as date table’? can I have 2 tables marked as date table?
[image]

This new 'Dim Date' shall be used only as a filter in the pbix, I  dont plan on using any time intelligence on it...

Answer (score 0):

It depends:

The analysis services tabular engine that power bi runs on supports multiple connections between tables. I would generally recommend using this with the USERELATIONSHIP() function and then your measures will give context to the report.

However, I have found there are situations where using USERELATIONSHIP() in many measures can introduce unnecessary complexity in your model. You can end up with far too many measures and it can get confusing when you use two measures that are using two different relationships in the same visual.

In short: There is not anything inherently wrong with duplicating a dimension but for data storage optimization and model cleanliness I would be sure USERELATIONSHIP() with multiple relationships between fact and dimension will NOT work before duplicating the dimension.