Problem Configuring Multiple Date Relationships in SSAS Multidimensional
I'm currently working on a multidimensional cube in SQL Server Analysis Services (SSAS) with SQL Server Data Tools (SSDT). My data model includes a fact table called FACT_TICKET containing several date columns (DATE_CREATE_KEY, DATE_NEW_KEY, DATE_PLANNED_KEY, DATE_INCOURSE_KEY, DATE_RESOLVED_KEY) and a single date dimension (DIM_DATE). I configured each date column in the fact table as a separate dimension, which is not ideal and makes analysis more complex. My goal is to correctly configure the relationships between each date column of FACT_TICKET and DIM_DATE
I want to have one dimension table for all dates not like this

Hi - this type question seems to have been asked and answered a few times already e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71615503/problems-with-having-2-dim-dates-in-ssas-power-bi
